# Как передать аргументы в staticmethod?

Tags: python

Есть класс родитель который реализует статический метод

```
class Shape :
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def get_distance (figure1, figure2):
        rez = math.sqrt(math.pow(figure2-figure1,2)+math.pow(figure2-figure1,2))
        return print (rez)
```

Аргументами метода `get_distance(figure1, figure2)` я хочу передать экземпляры классов фигур которые наследуют от родителя положения х и у
То есть у меня есть еще 2 класса:

```
class Square (Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, a=1):
        self.a = a
        Shape.__init__(self, x, y)
class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, a=1):
        self.a = a
        Shape.__init__(self, x, y)
```

Из этих классов создаю экземпляры и хочу передать значения x y , третий аргумент а передаваться не должен

Comment: функция `print()` ничего не возвращает, поэтому ваш метод `get_distance` будет возвращать `None`. Ну и в формуле надо заменить экземпляры классов на их свойства (x,y)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы хотите получить, что-то вроде этого?

```
from math import sqrt

class Shape:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def get_distance (figure1, figure2):
        rez = sqrt(pow(figure2.x-figure1.x,2)+pow(figure2.y-figure1.y,2))
        return rez

class Square (Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, a=1):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.a = a

class Triangle(Shape):
    def __init__(self, x, y, a=1):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.a = a

sq = Square(30,30)
tr = Triangle(60,70)
dist = Shape.get_distance(sq,tr)

print(dist)  # 50.0
```